# Can only update a mounted or mounting component.

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently working on a personal project and i'm getting this error

`Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the Graph component.`

I also get the same issue for my `App component.` I've done some reading on what the issue could be, but i'm non the wiser as to what the issue is with my code specifically.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a link to the [running project (with sourcecode) on CodeSnadbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/qv5vl50j1w) I've linked the offending code below as well.

Here is the `Graph Component`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Line, Doughnut, Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import moment from "moment";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import styleConstants from "../misc/style_constants.js";

class Graph extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      label: "default",
      dataset: [],
      labels: []
    };
  }

  /**
   * https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/ for documentation
   */
  async getHistoryData(ticker = "BTC", currency = "USD", filter = "close") {
    try {
      let response = await fetch(
        `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=${ticker}&tsym=${currency}&limit=60&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG`
      );
      const responseJson = await response.json();
      const dataset = responseJson.Data.map(data => {
        return data[filter];
      });
      const labels = responseJson.Data.map(data => {
        return moment(new Date(data.time * 1000)).format("MMM Do YY");
      });

      this.setState({ dataset: dataset });
      this.setState({ labels: labels });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { ticker, currency, filter } = this.props;
    this.getHistoryData(ticker, currency, filter);
  }

  render() {
    const { label, graphType } = this.props;
    const { dataset, labels } = this.state;

    const options = {
      legend: {
        fontColor: styleConstants.get("Dark")
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [
          {
            ticks: {
              fontColor: styleConstants.get("Light"),
              beginAtZero: true,
              callback: function(value, index, values) {
                if (parseInt(value) >= 1000) {
                  return (
                    "$" + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
                  );
                } else {
                  return "$" + value;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        xAxes: [
          {
            ticks: {
              fontColor: styleConstants.get("Light"),
              fontSize: 10,
              stepSize: 1,
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    };

    const data = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: label,
          fill: true,
          lineTension: 0.1,
          backgroundColor: styleConstants.get("Medium"),
          borderColor: styleConstants.get("Medium"),
          borderCapStyle: "butt",
          borderDash: [],
          borderDashOffset: 0.0,
          borderJoinStyle: "miter",
          pointBorderColor: styleConstants.get("Light"),
          pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
          pointBorderWidth: 1,
          pointHoverRadius: 5,
          pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
          pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
          pointRadius: 1,
          pointHitRadius: 10,
          data: dataset
        }
      ]
    };
    return <Line data={data} options={options} />;
    // switch (graphType) {
    //   case "line":
    //     return <Line data={data} options={options} />;
    //     break;
    //   case "bar":
    //     return <Bar data={data} options={options} />;
    //     break;
    //   case "doughnut":
    //     return <Doughnut data={data} options={options} />;
    //     break;
    //   default:
    //     return null;
    // }
  }
}

Graph.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string,
  graphType: PropTypes.string
};

Graph.defaultProps = {
  label: "Default String",
  graphType: "Default String"
};

export default Graph;
```

Here is the App Component also

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

import styleConstants from "../misc/style_constants.js";

import Overview from "../components/Overview";
import Panel from "../components/Panel";
import Table from "../components/Table";

import Options from "./Options";
import Graph from "./Graph";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedTicker: "BTC",
      currency: "USD",
      tickers: [],
      overview: []
    };
    this.updateTicker = this.updateTicker.bind(this);
    this.createGraph = this.createGraph.bind(this);
  }

  updateTicker(selectedValue) {
    const { value } = selectedValue;
    this.setState({ selectedTicker: value });
  }

  async getTickers() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')
      const responseJSON = await response.json();
      this.setState({ tickers: responseJSON });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("App getTickers() ", error);
    }
  }

  async getOverviewData() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/global/?convert=${this.state.currency}`)
      const responseJSON = await response.json();
      this.setState({ overview: responseJSON });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("App getOverviewData() ", error);
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTickers();
    this.getOverviewData();
  }

  createGraph(ticker = "", currency = "", graphType = "", label = "", filter = "") {
    return (
      <Graph
        filter={filter}
        ticker={ticker}
        currency={currency}
        graphType={graphType}
        label={label}
      />
    )
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedTicker, currency } = this.state;
    const Container = styled.div`
      input:focus,
      select:focus,
      textarea:focus,
    `;

    const Title = styled.h1`
      text-align: center;
      color: ${styleConstants.get('Yellow')};
    `;

    const LightSpan = styled.span`
      font-weight: 200;
    `;

    return (
      <Container>
        <Title>
          Coin:<LightSpan>Dash</LightSpan>
        </Title>
        <Overview {...this.state.overview} />
        <Options
          selectedValue={this.state.selectedTicker}
          values={this.state.tickers.map(data => {
            return data.symbol;
          })}
          labels={
            this.state.tickers.map(data => {
              return data.id;
            })
          }
          updateTicker={this.updateTicker} />
        <Panel label={"Price Action"} content={this.createGraph(selectedTicker, currency, 'line', "Close", "close")} />
        <Panel label={"Highest Price"} content={this.createGraph(selectedTicker, currency, 'bar', "High", "high")} />
        <Panel label={"Lowest Price"} content={this.createGraph(selectedTicker, currency, 'bar', "Low", "low")} />
        <Panel label={"Top Ten List"} content={
          <Table header={["Rank", "Name", "Price", "Change(24 Hour)"]} collection={this.state.tickers} />

        } />

      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `App` component also encounters this error? Does `App` ever get unmounted?

Comment: At no point do I ever unmount explicitly, but i'm not aware of the different ways of unmounting components. I will look into it.

Comment: Hmm.. I see something that might be a problem. Can you try changing the prop in `Panel` to an anonymous function? `content={() => {this.createGraph(selectedTicker, currency, 'line', "Close", "close")}` I think that function is going to be immediately invoked when you write it that way.

Comment: Your sandbox fails with a `Cannot read property 'length' of null`.

Comment: I've resolved that, it was due to a test, i've removed it since.

Comment: @Andrew It still complains about the issue.

Comment: The sandbox that is linked in the question still fails with that error. But the problem with your code is most likely the stateless functional components you define inside `Table`. These will be created fresh on every render, causing them and all their descendants to remount.

Comment: @Oblosys I apologize for the errors with the coding sandbox, I thought I had corrected the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by stateless functional components that are defined inside the `render` method of `App`. If you define the following functions outside of the `App` class, the error is fixed:

```
const Container = styled.div`
      input:focus,
      select:focus,
      textarea:focus,
    `;

const Title = styled.h1`
      text-align: center;
      color: ${styleConstants.get('Yellow')};
    `;

const LightSpan = styled.span`
      font-weight: 200;
    `;

export default class App extends Component {
..
```

The reason for the failure is that locally created SFC's change on each render, which causes them to unmount and remount, even though the rendering stays the same. There are also some other local SFC's in the `Table` component, which did not create any warning, but do cause unnecessary remounting.

UPDATE: It was a bit of a puzzle, but the remaining warning came from one of the tests:

```
describe("App", () => {
  it("renders without crashing", () => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
  });
});
```

Which makes sense, as you unmount the component before the async action is completed.

Here's a working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/24o6vp4rzp (I've also removed the arrow function in `content={..}`, since that needs to be a value)

Comment: I've made the changes, but it's still generating the same message.

Comment: Ah yes, they only show on a reload. Maybe there are some more local SFC's, let me check.